# Prevention of substantial edit by new user?

Tags: discussion

I reviewed an attempted edit by a new user who had not posted any question or answer and who had begun their activity with the site in attempting a substantial and wholly unwarranted edit of an answer.

I was surprised that this was possible.

The page I reviewed (I voted against the edit and it has been unsuccessful) is https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/51850

Comment: In fact, even users without an account (i.e., anonymous users) can suggest edits. Here is the FAQ post about suggested edits: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)

Comment: We do occasionally see things like this - often a new user has logged in anonymously one time and then with an account another time and wants to edit their original post, or things like that. Jumping in with this kind of edit is unusual, but it happens - I suppose that's why we have review processes in place!

Comment: The queue lists it as rejected, so it has been resolved in that much. Yeah, suggested edits can come many ways.